# How do I change my IP address so that it would reflect that I am located in a specific state inside the US?

Tags: ip-address, proxy, vpn

I would like to know the best method of changing my IP address to show that I am located in a specific state, Texas to be more precise.

I have to sign into a VPN service (powered by Cisco) that checks to make sure my IP is located in a specific state inside the US. So this method would have to be able to work while signed into said VPN. I would be signed into this VPN from anywhere between 4 to 10 hours at a time. So again the connection would have to show that I am located in that specific state for that amount of time.

Any information/direction would be greatly appreciated. I do not mind paying a reasonable monthly fee as long as the connection would be reliable and not show where my location really is.

Answer (score 1):

you can create another VPN. there are services, or you can rent a server(virtual or dedicated) to redirect your connection there. just find a serverfarm that has the datacenter in texas.